# How to free x509_store in newer versions of openssl lib

Tags: openssl, x509

While using older versions of openssl(1.02k), I used to cleanup x509 using following snipprt:-

> ```
> X509_VERIFY_PARAM_free(om->cert_store->param);
> sk_X509_OBJECT_free(om->cert_store->objs);
> sk_X509_LOOKUP_free(om->cert_store->get_cert_methods);
> OPENSSL_free(om->cert_store);
> ```

While using newer openssl library(1.1.1f) i encountered an error where X509_STORE type is no longer accessible via x509v3.h header file. Unable to find the right APIs. please help.

Comment: That wasn't the right way even in 1.0.2: you aren't handling the _elements_ of get_cert_methods and objs. Most OpenSSL objects have always been managed with a `TYPENAME_{new,free}` pair, and specifically **`X509_STORE_{new,free}` have been in the API since 0.9.8 at least** (I can't easily confirm earlier, but I bet they were). (Also this isn't particularly related to TLS1.2, or even SSL/TLS generally -- X.509 certs and verification of them are used for other things as well. And the definition used to be in x509_vfy.h not x509v3.h. v1 certs could and still can be verified.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @dave_thompson_085. I cannot recollect why I tried the above code instead of simply calling X509_STORE_free !